# Form input as parameters Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I want to dynamically query using dynamic values from form inputs

My form looks like this

```
<form action="{{url('search')}} method="post">
 <input name="min" type="number">
 <input name="max" type="number">
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Routes

```
Route::post('search', 'SearchController@search');
```

Action

```
public function search($min, $max)

{
   $max = //this should from form
   $min= //this should from form
   $result = $this->users->showResultByAgeMinMax($max,$min);//some code for repository


}
```

How whould I pass data from form as values for min, max as parameters?

```
 $min = 15;//works
 $max = 100;//works//
```

But I want this dynamically populated from form by a user

Comment: Also you need to pass csrf_token, just add input field to your form `<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Answer (score 1):

There are few methods to do that.

**1. Request object (recommended).**

```
public function search(Request $request)

{
   $max = $request->input("max");
   $min= $request->input("min");
   $result = $this->users->showResultByAgeMinMax($max,$min);//some code for repository


}
```

Or:

```
public function search(Request $request)

{
   $max = $request->get("max");
   $min= $request->get("min");
   $result = $this->users->showResultByAgeMinMax($max,$min);//some code for repository


}
```

**2. Input facade.**

```
public function search()

{
   $max = Input::get("max");
   $min= Input::get("min");
   $result = $this->users->showResultByAgeMinMax($max,$min);//some code for repository

}
```

**3. PHP $_POST superglobal.**

```
public function search()

{
   $max = $_POST["max"];
   $min= $_POST["min"];
   $result = $this->users->showResultByAgeMinMax($max,$min);//some code for repository

}
```